# Php contains mysql which contains IN condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have php file to unfavourite certain items.

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$UID = $_POST['UID'];
$OIDs = $_POST['OIDs'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE tblFavourite SET IsFavourite=0 WHERE UID='$UID'and OID IN ('$OID') ");

echo $query; 

?>
```

in my `$OIDs` value is coming as a string from my android application.

for example values are

$UID=9 and
$OIDs=18,8,6,10

when am applying that value directly in IN condition it doesnt work since it needs integers.

IN condition needs (18,8,6,10)  ..but all numbers are different integers not a string.

I am very new in php..any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Stop using [**`mysql_* extension`**](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) , it's deprecated and no longer been used in php7;

Comment: @hassan  which should i use?

Comment: [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single quote from $OID variable

```
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE tblFavourite SET IsFavourite=0 WHERE UID='$UID'and OID IN (".$OID.") ");
```